# Laravel передача значения из БД в View

Tags: php, laravel

```html
public function showall(){


    $boats = Boats::all();
    $name = Boats::get('name');


     return view('categories/motor-boats')
        ->with('boats', $boats)
        ->with('name', $name)
       ;  
     
    }
```

На фронтенде у меня конструкция

```html
@foreach($boats as $boat)
{{ $boat->name }}
@endforeach
```

Проблемма в том что мне нужно переменную name пропустить через функцию

```html
$slug = Str::slug($name, '-');
```

А потом передать на фронтенд.
Подскажите как это сделать.
Так как если я передаю

```html
->with('name', $name)
```

То у меня на фронтенд отображается целый массив из БД.
Как мне вытянуть один елемент, чтобы пропустить его через слаг, чтобы уже потом его вставить в foreach.

Comment: А что вам мешает передать так `->with('name', Str::slug($name, '-'));` ?

Comment: Ничего не мешает, но проблемма не пропадает. Мне передает целый массив который нужно распарсить по одному значению..

Comment: Укажите в вопросе содержимое `$name` и что вы из него хотите получить на входе в view. А то от вашей фразы "целый массив который нужно распарсить по одному значению" кровь из глаз идёт

Answer (score 2):

Нашел функцию которой решил вопрос

```html
$title = str_slug("Laravel 5 Framework", "-");
```

// laravel-5-framework
Она вставляется в скобки {{}} и работает

Я хотел сделать человекопонятный  URL. В итоге сдеал с помощью

```html
{{ str_slug("Laravel 5 Framework", "-")}}
```

Comment: В чем тогда был вопрос, если `str_slug()` - это просто алиас `Str::slug()`, которую вы уже используете?

Comment: Я мог получить слаг в контроллере, но не мог потом передать его в View.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте акцесор в моделе Boats:

```
public function getSlugAttribute()
{
    return Str::slug($this->name, '-');
}
```

В шаблоне:

```
@foreach($boats as $boat)
    {{ $boat->slug }}
@endforeach
```

Но я бы рекомендовал хранить слаг в базе данных.

Answer (score 1):

Передайте при вызове view() в контроллере:

```
return view('categories/motor-boats', [
    'name' => $name
]);
```